# cytoscape.js find connected node with data field value

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I have a graph set up in cytoscape.js. Some nodes in it have a data field "feature = true". For a node I select, I want to find the closest connected node that has "feature = true".

I've looked through the different algorithms, but if they accept selectors that validate to multiple nodes, they don't seem to behave in the expected manner of returning the shortest path to a node that matches the selector. For example, if I'm looking for the closest node to #start that has feature = true in its data field:

```js
var closestFeatureSearch = cytoGraph.elements().aStar({  
  root: '#start',
  goal: 'node[?feature]',
  directed : false
});
```

It appears to always pick the same ending node...the first item on the list returned if you did cytoGraph.filter('[?feature]') no matter which node I put into root, even if other nodes that have "feature = true" are closer.

Am I missing something obvious here? I've consulted the docs and can't find anything for this specific problem, just specific node-to-node use cases. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that A* is for when you know the exact node you want to be the destination.  Thus, only one node is accepted as the goal.  If you specify a collection of size more than 1, then only the first can be used.

I haven't looked at the algorithm recently, but my intuition is that your change might not work for all cases -- especially in tandem with the heuristic.

It's probably better for you to use Djikstra.  After running, you can look at the distance it finds for every [?feature] node -- use the smallest one, and get its path.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was able to add a case to handle this functionality. Going off the un-minified current version (2.7.8) around line 390 you should see a conditional like so:

```js
if( cMin.id() == target.id() ){
  var rPath = reconstructPath( source.id(), target.id(), cameFrom, [] );
  rPath.reverse();
  return {
    found: true,
    distance: gScore[ cMin.id() ],
    path: eles.spawn( rPath ),
    steps: steps
  };
}
```

I added a separate case for handling passing in filters that match multiple items immediately following it:

```js
//if there was a filter passed in, check the array of ids matching that to see if cMin.id() is in there
if (is.string( options.goal ) && this.filter( options.goal ).map(function(item){return item.id()}).indexOf(cMin.id()) > -1 ) {
  var rPath = reconstructPath( source.id(), cMin.id(), cameFrom, [] );
  rPath.reverse();
  return {
    found: true,
    distance: gScore[ cMin.id() ],
    path: eles.spawn( rPath ),
    steps: steps
  };
}
```

The key two changes are the if condition (obviously) and that rPath takes the current cMin.id() as the destination, instead of target.id().

Anyway, it works for my use case! Hope it's useful to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var closestFeatureSearch = cytoGraph.elements().aStar({     
  root: '#start',
  goal: 'node[?feature]',
  directed : false
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please explain your answer, see [How To Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)